# MSBuild: check that referenced projects match convention

Tags: .net, msbuild, target

In my repository there are several projects. Some of them reference others in the standard way. As an example, my standard *.csproj file looks like this:

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFrameworks>net7.0-windows</TargetFrameworks>
    <OutputType>Library</OutputType>
    <ProjectGuid>{6b123456-412f-7941-cfcc-f021137c2341}</ProjectGuid>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile ... />
    <Compile ... />
    ...
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Project1\Project1.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Project2\Project2.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

I want to add an MSBuild pre-build step which ensures that all the referenced projects meet specific convention. In my case this means that referenced projects' names can't end with ".Execute".

I started defining the Target, but I have no idea how to:

- retrieve the list of project's dependencies
- iterate over the dependencies

My current code:

```xml
  <Target Name="EnsureNonExecute" BeforeTargets="Build">
    <!-- How to iterate over the list of referenced projects? -->
  </Target>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MSBuild is a declarative language. There are no iterative loops. Instead, MSBuild uses '[batching](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-batching?view=vs-2022)' to work with item lists. The `ItemGroup` element is used to create item lists.

In your project, an item list named `ProjectReference` is created that contains items for 'Project1' and 'Project2'.

For demonstration purposes let's say that `ProjectReference` has a project whose name ends with '.Execute', e.g.:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Project1\Project1.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Project2\Project2.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Project3\Project3.Execute.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

An item has [metadata](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-well-known-item-metadata?view=vs-2022). One of the standard metadata values is `Filename`, which is the filename without the file extension. The following target will display the `Filename` of each item by batching:

```
  <Target Name="EnsureNonExecute" BeforeTargets="Build">
    <Message Text="%(ProjectReference.Filename)" />
  </Target>
```

The output will be:

```
EnsureNonExecute:
  Project1
  Project2
  Project3.Execute
```

MSBuild properties support string methods like `EndsWith()` but metadata values are not properties. There is a common 'trick' to create a property from a metadata value. The static string `Copy` method is called passing the metadata value.

The `EnsureNonExecute` target may be written as follows:

```
  <Target Name="EnsureNonExecute" BeforeTargets="Build">
    <PropertyGroup>
      <ExecuteNameSuffix>.Execute</ExecuteNameSuffix>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <Error
      Text="Project $(MSBuildProjectFile) has a reference to &quot;@(ProjectReference)&quot;. Referenced projects' names can't end with &quot;$(ExecuteNameSuffix)&quot;."
      Condition="$([System.String]::Copy('%(Filename)').EndsWith('$(ExecuteNameSuffix)'))" />
  </Target>
```

If your project is named 'Fred.csproj', then the target will report an error as follows:

```
error : Project Fred.csproj has a reference to "../Project3/Project3.Execute.csproj". Referenced projects' names can't end with ".Execute".
```

I would suggest that you want to fail quick if the error condition exists. Instead of `BeforeTargets="Build"`, consider `BeforeTargets="BeforeBuild"`.

Comment: Bro, this is absolutely A-MA-ZING! Thanks!

Comment: For my education, why do I need `[System.String]::Copy` in the Error Target?

Comment: We want to call `EndsWith()` on the value of `Filename`. But `%(ProjectReference.Filename).EndsWith('$(ExecuteNameSuffix)')` will not work. It will be evaluated as literal text, e.g 'Project1.EndsWith('.Execute')'. We need a property because `EndsWith()` is supported as a 'property function'. Surrounding a metadata value with `$(` and `)` doesn't convert to a property. e.g. `$(%(ProjectReference.Filename)).EndsWith('$(ExecuteNameSuffix)')` doesn't work. But calling a static property function and passing the metadata value as an argument will work. (Yes, it is a strange quirk.)

Comment: It's not a quirk. It's a kind of magic and that's the right way to cast these spells. Thanks a lot! :)